# hive syntax for returning arrays and structs

Tags: hadoop, hive

i need a query that returns arrays and structs. i tried:

```
select Array(1) from my_table limit 1;
```

and it works but gives some errors:

> ERROR optimizer.ConstantPropagateProcFactory: Unable to evaluate
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFArray@11bd210b. Return
>   value unrecoginizable.

same for structs:

```
select Struct(1,2) from my_table limit 1;
```

works and returns

```
{"col1":1,"col2":2}
```

how to set column names?

it also prints an error

> ERROR optimizer.ConstantPropagateProcFactory: Unable to evaluate
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFStruct@1d04de1f.
>   Return value unrecoginizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the column names or select * in order to return the actual columns and data in your table.

```
select Array(*) from yourTableName limit 1;
select Array(field1,field2) from yourTableName limit 1;
select Struct(*) from yourTableName limit 1;
select Struct(field1,field2) from yourTableName limit 1;
```